# How to restore or recreate a broken layout in Android Studio

Tags: android

I am reasonably new to Android Studio development.  An app that I am writing is working well.  Until that is, I added a couple of extra buttons to the layout!  In doing so I have destroyed the layout somewhat - the titlebar has been moved down from the top and the three dots menu is nearer the middle than the right.

Is there any way that I can restore the layout or, perhaps better, to reapply one of the standard layouts to the existing project.  Or am I better starting again with the layout and copying the code to it...that seems a bit drastic!

I've already tried:  Window->Restore Default Layout

Here is the activity_main.xml text:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
     xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:id="@+id/coordinatorLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        tools:context=".MainActivity">

        <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
            android:id="@+id/appBarLayout"
            android:layout_width="368dp"
            android:layout_height="59dp"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/include"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintVertical_chainStyle="packed">

            <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
                android:id="@+id/toolbar"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
                app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay" />

        </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

        <include
            android:id="@+id/include"
            layout="@layout/content_main"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="529dp"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/appBarLayout" />

    </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: Use Ctrl + Z to undo your changes on files. Or you can create Basic or Empty layout from New menu by right click on layout folder in Android Studio.

Answer (score 1):

I'd like to take a moment and put in a plug for version control. Version control lets you make changes and commit them along the way. If you get yourself into a spot you don't know how to fix, you can revert your changes back to the last committed state. If you place the code into, for example github, you will be able to see any and all changes/commits you've ever made. Without version control, you will have to use cmd-z or crtl-z which only goes back so far.

I use git. It has a huge community and everyone is very helpful. Here's a beginning tutorial: https://guides.github.com/introduction/git-handbook/

Comment: Thank you Stephen.
To be honest, I should have looked into version control earlier.   I use it in Perl, the language I use most, but jumped straight in with developing an Android app.  I have added the tutorial to my reading list.

Answer (score 0):

In case it's setting only for current application, you can just invalidate cache and restart.

`On the main menu, choose **File | Invalidate Caches/Restart**. The Invalidate Caches message appears informing you that the caches will be invalidated and rebuilt on the next start. Use buttons in the dialog to invalidate caches, restart JetBrains Rider or both.`

Other possible solution, it's just open your project and delete local setting. Close project in IDEA, open project in explorer and delete folder `.idea`. Then import your source from initial IDEA screen again.

Comment: Thanks - I've now tried "Invalidate Caches/Restart" and it hasn't helped.  It has made a change though so that when the button with event listeners are clicked, the app minimises which is a bit strange...

Answer (score 0):

How complex is the layout?  Could you paste the code please.  Have you looked in the text editor?  The issue may be more apparent on there than the layout editor.

Comment: I've updated the question to include activity_main.xml